# How do I fix an issue where my website only shows in HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html, css, github-pages

I used javascript, css, html, bootstrap and jquery for my portfolio website. When I look at the live preview in Brackets, it shows perfectly fine with the style/custom hamburger menu/font/everything. I uploaded the files onto my github pages repo and loaded up my site a little while after, only to see that it is just in full HTML.

Like, my menu has disappeared and the nav bar is a simple list and the font is the Times New Roman font that comes standard w/ html. What can I do to fix this? I'm not really sure what caused the issue. Here's what my github repo looks like for the site: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVnkI.png

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post [a minimal example of what needs to change](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a lot like the HTML document is missing or unable to locate the corresponding CSS stylesheet. Therefore you likely need to provide an absolute path of the CSS stylesheet, as opposed to a relative path, in your HTML document.

You need to do something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://github.com/path/to/your/stylesheet/css/portfolio.css">
...
```

Instead of something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/portfolio.css">
...
```